# Too many API calls causing error 'Can't set headers after they are sent'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have to retrieve data for multiple dropdown lists which occur one after another when the component mounts, also I have set up notification/status calls in my main component that has all the navigation bars and holds the rest of my components. The problems are these notifications/status calls are interfering with the component making calls and causing the errors can't set headers after they are sent. If I turn off my notifications/status calls then the data for the dropdown lists can be retrieved, but right now my app can do either or not both. I don't know if this is a design flaw, or maybe I need to integrate Promises, right now I use fetch to make all my calls. My backend is express JS and its making calls to another backend in PHP. I am also using a proxy server since create-react-app and express cant be on the same port.

I have researched the issue and tried using Promise.resolve in my server but this did not solve the issue.

CreateEndpoint.js

```
componentDidMount(){
     this.getData()
  }

  async getData() {

    let data = [
            "contact_phone","contact_point","contract_id",
            "customer","display_name","ep_id","equip_model",
            "equip_type","location","maintenance_type",
            "manufacturer","region","tech_support_group"
            ]

    let attributesObj = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      let newData = await fetch(`/api/endpointAttributeValues/${data[i]}`).then(res => res.json()).catch(err => this.setState({redirect: true}))
      let attributeName = data[i]
      attributesObj[attributeName] = newData.data;
    }

    this.setState({attributeValues: attributesObj})
}
```

AsyncApp.js (all components are housed in this main component)

```
class AsyncApp extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this)
    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      redirect: false,
      maxSessionInactivity: null,
      showAlert: false,
      sinceLastCheck: ''
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.show = null
    let self = this
    let messages;
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    await document.body.addEventListener("keypress", this.handleEvent);
    await document.body.addEventListener("click", this.handleEvent);

    if(this._isMounted){

      await fetch('/api/getStatus').then(res => res.json()).then(function(res){
        if(!res.data.is_active){
          self.setState({redirect: true})
        }
        console.log("IN GET STATUS ", res)
      })
      .catch(err => self.setState({redirect: true}))

      await fetch('/api/getFirstNotification')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(function(res){
        // if(res.status.errorOccured){
        //   self.setState({redirect: true})
        // }
        messages = res.data.messages
        dispatch(updateMessages(res.data.messages))
        self.setState({sinceLastCheck: res.data.since_last_check})
      })
      .catch(err => self.setState({redirect: true}))

    }
    await fetch('/api/getStatus').then(res => res.json()).then(res => this.setState({maxSessionInactivity: res.data.session_inactivity_minutes - 1 * 1000}));
     await this.startTimer()
     await console.log("STATE J", this.state)
     await this.interval(messages)
     await this.notifications()
  }

  startTimer() {
     this.firstTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        this.setState({showAlert: true})
     }.bind(this), 100000);
     this.lastTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        this.setState({redirect: true})
     }.bind(this), 600000)
  }

  handleEvent(e){
    console.log("event", e)
    clearTimeout(this.firstTimer)
    clearTimeout(this.lastTimer)
    this.startTimer()
  }

  async interval(messages){
    this.intervalStatus = await setInterval(async () => {
      await this.notify(messages)
    }, 60000)
  };

  async notifications(){

    const { dispatch } = this.props

    this.newNotifications = await setInterval( async () => {

      let data = { since_last_checked : this.state.sinceLastCheck }
      let res1 = await fetch('/api/getNotifications', {
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

      console.log("NOTIFICATIONS NEXTTT", res1)

      if(res1 === undefined || res1.data === undefined || res1.data === null){
        this.setState({redirect: true})
      }

      if(res1 != undefined && res1.data != null) dispatch(updateMessages(res1.data.messages))

      let res2 = await fetch('/api/getStatus')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

      console.log("STATUSS", res2)

      if(res2 === undefined || res2.data === undefined || res2.data === null || res2.data.is_active === 'N' || res2.data.status === 'closed'){
        this.setState({redirect: true})
      }

    }, 5000)

  }

  handleClose(event){
   this.setState({showAlert: false})
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log("componentWillUnmount!!!!")
    this._isMounted = false
    clearInterval(this.newNotifications)
    clearInterval(this.intervalStatus)
    clearTimeout(this.firstTimer)
    clearTimeout(this.lastTimer)
    document.body.removeEventListener("keypress", this.handleEvent);
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", this.handleEvent);
  }

  notify(arr){
    if(arr === undefined) return null

    if(typeof arr === 'string'){
      return toast.success(`${arr}`)
    }

    if(arr.length < 4){
      let messages = arr.map(message => toast.success(`${message.message_text}`))
      return messages
    } else {
      return toast.success(`You have ${arr.length} new Notifications!`)
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props

    if (this.state.redirect) return <Redirect to="/logout" />

    return (
      <div>
        <ToastContainer />
        <Snackbar
          anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'left',
          }}
          open={this.state.showAlert}
          autoHideDuration={6000}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MySnackbarContentWrapper
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            variant="warning"
            message="Your session will expire in one minute!"
          />
        </Snackbar>

        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <nav className={classes.drawer}>
              <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
                <Navigator PaperProps={{ style: { width: drawerWidth } }} />
              </Hidden>
            </nav>
            <div className={classes.appContent}>
              <Header onDrawerToggle={this.handleDrawerToggle} />
              <main className={classes.mainContent}>
                <div>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/EditContracts/:contractId/sections/:section" component={EditSection} />
                    <Route exact path="/EditContracts/:contractId" component={EditContract} />
                    <Route exact path="/EditUsers/:userId" component={EditUser} />
                    <Route exact path="/EditEndpoints/:epId" component={EditEndpoint} />
                    <Route exact path="/EditContracts/:contractId/addSection" component={CreateSection} />
                    <Route exact path="/Contracts/List" component={Contracts} />
                    <Route exact path="/Contracts/Create" component={CreateContract} />
                    <Route exact path="/Contracts/Import" component={ImportContract} />
                    <Route exact path="/Users/List" component={Users} />
                    <Route exact path="/Users/Create" component={CreateUser} />
                    <Route exact path="/Endpoints/Create" component={CreateEndpoint} />
                    <Route exact path="/Endpoints/List" component={Endpoints} />
                    <Route exact path="/Pug_Community" component={PugCommunity} />
                    <Redirect exact from="/Users" to="/Users/List" />
                    <Redirect exact from="/Endpoints" to="/Endpoints/List" />
                    <Redirect exact from="/Contracts" to="/Contracts/List" />
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </main>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

App.js (AsyncApp.js is housed in this component)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route exact path="/changePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/" component={AsyncApp} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

Root.js (App.js is housed in this component)

```
const store = configureStore()

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
         <App />
       </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

index.js (this is where all calls are rerouted hit another API in PHP through WebSockets)

```
app.get(`/api/endpointAttributeValues/:attr`, function(req, res) {

  var attribute = req.params.attr;

  console.log("Attribute123", attribute);

  stompClient = new StompJs.Client({
      connectHeaders: { login: "", passcode: "" },
      brokerURL: brokerURL,
      reconnectDelay: 200,
      //debug: (str) =>  { console.log("DEBUG", str) },
      onConnect: () => { sendCommandToPUG("get_values_for_attribute", "endpoints",  {"attribute_name": attribute}, stompClient, req.session.userID, req.session.pugSessionID); },
      onUnhandledMessage: (messageReply) => {

          reply = JSON.parse(messageReply.body);
          if(reply.status.errorOccured)
              console.log("PUG-SERVER RETURNED ERROR: " + reply.status.errorText);

          replyData = reply.data; //here is where you will find all the data that matches your query (eg: fields/rows)
          res.json(reply);
          //stompClient.disconnect();
      },
  });

  stompClient.activate();

});
```

The main error is can't set headers after they have been sent. I don't know whether I need to specify the headers on all my calls even forget requests. Maybe since I am using redux I should not make the API calls in the component but for large lists, gather all the information on my main component in the initial load and store it in redux?

Answer (score 1):

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written. For example, look for callbacks that are accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is sent.

I think onUnhandledMessage method is getting called multiple times and causing an issue. Try adding console.log there so that you can debug.

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

To prevent these type of error, you can add "return" before any res.

That way you won't me editing the data after they're sent.

Example for your case:

```
return res.json(reply);
```